# JavaScript + ExtendScript | retrieve a folder path from a variable & create a new folder inside

Tags: javascript, path, directory, extendscript

```
var targetFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Select a folder");
```

This is what I have. Now I need to retrieve the path to the selected folder and create a subfolder inside.

I know how to create a folder already:

```
var newFolder = new Folder("/C/namefolder/");
newFolder.create();
```

But do not know how to do the rest.

How can I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var targetFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Select a folder");
if (targetFolder !== null) {
  var insideFolder = new Folder(targetFolder.fsName + "/myNewFolder");
  insideFolder.create();
}
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339060/how-do-i-create-a-folder-using-extendscript)

Comment: Oh sorry, I am new here. Didn't know I could do that.